# Saml 2.0 Signature Validation fails

Tags: java, validation, digital-signature, saml-2.0, xml-signature

I am trying to do a signature verification for SAML 2.0 response, but facing an issue and getting the below error. Strange thing is if I use SunJSSE Provider I get "Signature length not correct: got 512 but was expecting 256", but if I use Bouncy Castle Provider then the below error

```
<ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></ds:SignatureMethod>
        <ds:Reference URI="#Assertion-uuidab41cfa-014b-103a-bfdc-b02f8a93776c">
           <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                 <xc14n:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:xc14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs saml xsi"></xc14n:InclusiveNamespaces>
              </ds:Transform>
           </ds:Transforms>
           <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>
           <ds:DigestValue>xRjm9aVPUGwyzxWuhWL9/M/To1DGh0KvWWceX+e6Gj4=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
     </ds:SignedInfo>
     WARN   2015-01-27  -   Signature verification failed.
     org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature did not validate against the credential's key
```

My code for verifying the signature is as follows

```
try {
        byte[] certByte = idp.getIdpDescriptor().getKeyDescriptors().get(0).getKeyInfo().getX509Datas().get(0).getX509Certificates().get(0).getValue().getBytes();
        InputStream ss = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(certByte));
        Certificate myCert = CertificateFactory
         .getInstance("X509").generateCertificate(ss);

        X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(myCert.getPublicKey().getEncoded());
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey key = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
        System.out.println(key.getEncoded().length);
        /*myCert = CertificateFactory
                 .getInstance("X509")
                 .generateCertificate(
                                   // string encoded with default charset
                new ByteArrayInputStream(idp.getIdpDescriptor().getKeyDescriptors().get(0).getKeyInfo().getX509Datas().get(0).getX509Certificates().get(0).getValue().getBytes("UTF-8"))
                 );*/
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) myCert;

        BasicX509Credential x509Credential = new BasicX509Credential();
        x509Credential.setPublicKey(cert.getPublicKey());
        x509Credential.setEntityCertificate(cert);
        x509Credential.getEntityCertificateChain().add(cert);
        Credential credential = x509Credential;
        SignatureValidator sigValidator = new SignatureValidator(
                credential);
        sigValidator.validate(assertion.getSignature());
        System.out.println("Validated.....YYIIIIIPPPPPEEEEEEEEEEEE");
    } catch (CertificateException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am new to java security so can't figure it out. I am also putting my SAML Response as below.

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="uuidab41d1c-014b-15f6-b5cd-b02f8a93776c">
     <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
        <ds:Reference URI="#Assertion-uuidab41cfa-014b-103a-bfdc-b02f8a93776c">
           <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                 <xc14n:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:xc14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs saml xsi" />
              </ds:Transform>
           </ds:Transforms>
           <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
           <ds:DigestValue>xRjm9aVPUGwyzxWuhWL9/M/To1DGh0KvWWceX+e6Gj4=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
     </ds:SignedInfo>
     <ds:SignatureValue>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</ds:SignatureValue>
     <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
           <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
     </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
```

Below mentioned is the IDP Metadata

```
<md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true"
    protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>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
                </X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
        <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"></md:EncryptionMethod>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>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
                </X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
        <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:ArtifactResolutionService
        Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://www-test.com.au/sps/login/saml20/soap"
        index="0" isDefault="true" />
    <md:SingleLogoutService
        Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://www-test.com.au/sps/login/saml20/slo" />
    <md:SingleLogoutService
        Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        Location="https://www-test.com.au/sps/login/saml20/slo" />
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
    </md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
    </md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
    </md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:encrypted
    </md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
    </md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:SingleSignOnService
        Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://www-test.com.au/sps/login/saml20/login" />
    <md:SingleSignOnService
        Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        Location="https://www-test.com.au/sps/login/saml20/login" />
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
```

Comment: Could you post the SAML metadata you har using (getIdpDescriptor()) on gist and link to it?

Comment: Added the idp descriptor

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% here but it sounds like the SAMLResponse is specifying 1 signature method but actually using a different one to generate the signature. The message is telling the SP to use sha256 for validation:

> ```
> <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></ds:SignatureMethod>
> ```

but the signature validation code is smart enough to realize it is really something else (sha512?). Since the two don't match, the signature is invalid. See what happens when the two match as expected.